# Standarized prefixes for naming REST POJO (Bad or good practice)?

Tags: rest, coding-style, api-design, naming-standards

We are building a software application for a client with a particular naming convention for REST services.

For example if you use a POJO for your request or response in a REST service something like that:

```
public class Document {
    private String codeDocument;
    private String codeParentDocument;
    private Double amountPayed;
    private String nameOwner;
    private String descriptionDocument;
}
```

Your REST contract should be so:

```
{
  "codDocument": "123",
  "codParentDocument": "123",
  "amtPayed": 25.5,
  "desDocument": "owner"
}
```

[EDIT]

As you can see, some attributes names are using accronyms ("cod", "amt", "des"). There are many others that are used in this project.

I would like to know if the use of this "acronyms" can be considered as a bad practice or in contrast, don't break any good practice?

Thanks in advance for your opinions!

Comment: Ask yourself one question: is this really a battle worth fighting?

Comment: It depends, if your customer is doing a bad practice in software development. It could be a good opportunity at least, for trying to convince and guiding him. But..leaving aside the opinions of my customer. I would like to know if the use of this "acronyms" could be considered a bad practice. Maybe I should ask only that and  
don't mix my client's background. Thanks!

Comment: I personally don't like accronyms because if someone doesn't know what they mean they have that extra mental jump to find out. But it is not a question for api style or REST. What will cause you much more headaches is mapping your internal domain objects to your public Resources. That is going to make maintaining this system a nightmare. You should implement some mapping layer so your Java domain model can change independently of your public REST resources (which should not change)

Comment: This has nothing to do with REST at all, it is just a message format. For all practical purposes it is entirely irrelevant how json elements are called. The elements could be called 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' and it would make no difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming convention looks like a variant of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) where the acronyms correspond to semantic categories and replace the type.

As with all naming conventions: there is no good nor bad practice.  The most important point is to use the convention consistently.

To answer this question objectively, one could only look at pros and cons:

- The pros in your case seem to be consistency with the existing code, including applications consuming your project's interface. Another pro is the principle of least surprise, if the company has other projects using the same convention, especially if customers/partners are already used to it.
- The cons are the reduced readability, the ambiguity of acronyms used elsewhere than at beginning (e.g. is it `currencyAmt` or `currencyAmount`?),  the error-prone mixing of acronyms with plain names (e.g. was it `codParentDoc` or `codParentDocument`?),  the different convention for internal and external conventions.

If pros are aknowledged, thes shall outweight the cons.